# Trouble getting Rails 3 to work with MySQL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-plugins

Brand new at Rails. I had a simple Rails 3 app on OS X 10.6 going, using the default sqlite3 database.

I'm trying to convert that to use the MySQL server that I already have installed. (`mysql5 -uroot` works.) I'd like to use `mysql2`, which I installed and it said it was successful.

database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: myproject
  username: root
  socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Gemfile:

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rails', '3.0.6'
gem 'mysql2'
gem 'sqlite3'
```

More info:

```
$  bundle show mysql2
/Users/me/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/mysql2-0.3.2
```

The page loads with: "ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished"

I'm not sure if I'm supposed to create the `myproject` database myself manually or not. Regardless, I've tried it both ways.

I get:

```
$ rake db:schema:load
(in /Users/me/Sites/myproject/web)
WARNING: This version of mysql2 (0.3.2) doesn't ship with the ActiveRecord adapter bundled anymore as it's now part of Rails 3.1
WARNING: Please use the 0.2.x releases if you plan on using it in Rails <= 3.0.x
-- create_table("notes", {:force=>true})
rake aborted!
Please install the mysql2 adapter: `gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter` (no such file to load -- active_record/connection_adapters/mysql2_adapter)
```

I have tried to install that gem:

```
$ sudo gem install activerecord-mysql2-adapter
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'activerecord-mysql2-adapter' (>= 0) in any repository
```

From reading some [very similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1670154/convert-a-ruby-on-rails-app-from-sqlite-to-mysql), it seems what solves the problem for everyone else is just making sure the database.yml adapter says `mysql2`. I've already done this though and it didn't help...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this in Gemfile:

```
gem 'mysql2','0.2.7'
```

And then `bundle install`.

Note that mysql2 version 0.3.x is for Rails 3.1.x. For Rails 3.0.x, use the 0.2.x version of mysql2.

Ps. If you're not already using [rvm](https://rvm.io), I highly recommend using it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601003/how-to-downgrade-from-ruby-1-9-2-to-ruby-1-8-7-to-run-rails-2-0-2/4601098#4601098) for why rvm is so cool.